# Why is JS map() returning a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, function

In this simplified piece of code, I am passing an object that contains two properties to the function `normalize`.

```
function normalize() {  
  console.log(this.coords.map(n => n / this.length));  
}

normalize({coords: [0, 2, 3], length: 5});

// OUTPUT: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

It throws a TypeError.

On the other side, by *not* passing the object in the calling function it works:

```
    function normalize() {  
      console.log(obj.coords.map(n => n / obj.length));  
    }

    obj = {
        coords: [0, 2, 3],
        length: 5
    }

    normalize();
    // OUTPUT: [0, 0.4, 0.6]
```

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `map()` needs a calling array in order to be executed properly, and `coords`, seems to be passed (as an array) correctly in both examples.

Why does this happen? Whats wrong in the first code snippet?

Comment: You're passing in an argument, not a value for `this`.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be? You're passing an argument, why not define the parameter?

Comment: `console.log(arguments[0].coords.map(n => n / arguments[0].length)); ` should work .... or define the parameter as @jonrsharpe said.

Comment: @lealceldeiro `(normalize.bind({coords: [0, 2, 3], length: 5}))()` eventually ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing the data as a parameter, you want to use the parameter instead of using `this`.

so `this.coords` becomes `obj.coords` and `this.length` becomes `obj.length`.

```js
function normalize(obj) {
  console.log(obj.coords.map(n => n / obj.length));
}

normalize({
  coords: [0, 2, 3],
  length: 5
});
```

If you wanted to use this, then you would have to make the function a prototype like this, and then you wouldn't pass the items as a parameter (making prototypes like this usually isn't recommended):

```js
Object.prototype.normalize = function() {
  return this.coords.map(n => n / this.length);
}

console.log({
  coords: [0, 2, 3],
  length: 5
}.normalize());
```

Comment: Makes sense. Why that would work if I do: normalize.call({coords: [0, 2, 3], length: 5}) and not passing any parameter to the function.

Comment: @leonardofed because the first argument to `.call` is the context, which becomes `this`, not the parameters. [Read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: totally makes sense. Same with .apply and .bind I guess.